# coboundary map of the Eilenberg Chevalley complex

Tags: lie-algebras, homological-algebra

I'm studying Eilenberg and Chevalley's paper "Cohomology theory of lie groups and lie algebras". You can freely acces it here: https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1948-063-01/S0002-9947-1948-0024908-8/S0002-9947-1948-0024908-8.pdf

On page 115, the key definition of the differential of the Eilenberg Chevalley cochain complex, it says $$(\delta f)(x_1,...,x_{q+1})=\sum_{i=1}^{q+1}(-1)^{i+1}P(x_i)f(x_1,...,\hat{x_i},...,x_{q+1})+\sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j+1}f([x_i,x_j],x_1,...,\hat{x_i},...,\hat{x_j},...,x_n).$$

Is there a sign mistake for the second term on the right hand side? Other sources I checked says $(-1)^{i+j}$ instead. If we use Eilenberg and Chevalley's sign, we get that if $f$ is a linear map from the Lie algebra to the vector space then $$(\delta f)(x,y)=P(x)f(y)-P(y)f(x)+f([x,y])$$ which doesn't make sense. It also seems that Eilenberg Chevalley carried this sign to the entire paper. For example in the proof of section 25 page 119.

Comment: The correct sign must be the one that makes $\delta^2=0$.

Comment: @MathsIsFun so do you agree that the original paper seems to have a sign mistake?

Comment: It seems to be the case, yes. But just drop one of the 1's in the $(-1)^\alpha$ in the first sum or the second sum.

Answer (score 1):

I got something similar to the formula given in the cited paper. Let me present it below.

For simplicity, let's only consider the case where $V$ is the trivial representation of $\mathfrak{g}$ over a field $k$ of characteristic $0$, and we identify $\bigwedge^n(\mathfrak{g}^*)$ with $(\bigwedge^n \frak{g})^*$ via the following formula:
$$
(\varphi_1\wedge\dots\wedge\varphi_n) (v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_n) := \sum_{\sigma \in S_n} (-1)^\sigma \prod_{i=1}^n \varphi_i(v_{\sigma(i)}) = \det(\varphi_i(v_j)).
$$
[Recall](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Chevalley-Eilenberg+algebra#OfLieAlgebra) that the differential on $\bigwedge^{\bullet}\frak{g}^*$ is the unique graded derivation determined by $\frak{g}^*\to \frak{g}^*\wedge \frak{g}^*\cong (\bigwedge^2\frak{g})^*$ which is induced by the Lie bracket $[\mbox{ , }]:\bigwedge^2(\frak{g})\to \frak{g}$. Then, by the Leibniz rule

\begin{align*}
d(\varphi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \varphi_n)
&= (d\varphi_1\wedge \varphi_2\wedge\dots \varphi_n) - (\varphi_1\wedge d\varphi_2\wedge\dots \varphi_n) + \dots + (-1)^{n+1} (\varphi_1\wedge \varphi_2 \wedge \dots \wedge d\varphi_n)
\end{align*}

Evaluating at the vector $(v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_{n+1})$ yields

\begin{align*}
d(\varphi_1 \wedge \dots \wedge \varphi_n)(v_1 \wedge \dots \wedge v_{n+1})
&= 
\left[\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+1}} (-1)^\sigma \varphi_1([v_{\sigma(1)},v_{\sigma(2)}]) \varphi_2(v_{\sigma(3)})\dots \varphi_n(v_{\sigma(n+1)})\right] 
-
\left[\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+1}} (-1)^\sigma \varphi_1(v_{\sigma(1)})\varphi_2([v_{\sigma(2)},v_{\sigma(3)}]) \dots \varphi_n(v_{\sigma(n+1)})\right] 
+ \dots +
(-1)^{n+1} \left[\sum_{\sigma\in S_{n+1}} (-1)^\sigma \varphi_1(v_{\sigma(1)})\varphi_2(v_{\sigma(2)})\dots  \varphi_n([v_{\sigma(n)},v_{\sigma(n+1)}]) \right]
\end{align*}
which I believe is equal to
$$
2\cdot \sum_{i<j}(-1)^{i+j+1}(\varphi_1\wedge\dots\wedge\varphi_n)([v_i,v_j],v_1,...,\hat{v_i},...,\hat{v_j},...,v_{n+1}),
$$
where the factor of $2$ is there because, for example, $\varphi([v_1,v_2])=-\varphi([v_2,v_1])$. To check the equality, we fix any pair $i<j$ and compare both sides.

**Remark.**
To get rid of the factor of $2$, just use *half* of the Lie bracket to induce the initial map $\frak{g}^*\to \bigwedge^2\frak{g}^*$.